# why is the error occuring when i am running the script.how can i fix it?

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, scripting

Here is the script was written which is based on while loop in shell scripting in Linux.

I used a variable and wanted to increase the value of it till the value is less than 10. What problems could have occurred in the script?

To find out I ran the script and the error is coming.

[image: Image Reference]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) Also, make sure you submit both your code and the error you received.

Comment: Please in the future take your time and write your code and the error in the question by yourself.

Comment: It seems that `expr` statement has been enclosed with single-quotes. It should be back-quoted or `$(expr...)` kind of statement.

Comment: try using ((a++)) instead

Comment: @sungtm i tried your suggestion of back quotes and it worked out ..cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In line 6, try:

```
a=`expr $a + 1`
```

or

```
a=$(expr $a + 1)
```

not this

```
a='expr $a + 1'
```